# UITextView text support for another language -iOS7 app crash

Tags: ios, ios7, uitextview

My app is getting crash on `iOS7`

In my app, I have language option. One is **English** and other is **Kannada**.

When user selects Kannada, all text turns into Kannada. I have one `textview` in which I have added static text in Kannada.
When user navigates to that view, the app crashes on `iOS7` , while on `iOS8` it's working fine.

I am not getting any log for crash. I can only see `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1, ...)` . I have tried it by keeping "Enable Zombies" option, still not getting any log in console.

P.S. - I have static text in `textview`. I am not adding text dynamically. I am just hiding/un-hiding `textviews`. I can see and read the text in Kannada in my `textview` in storyboard.

Comment: You need to provide details about the crash.

Comment: Please provide reason for down-vote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a strange behavior in iOS 7, and it seems to be a bug in the way `NSLayoutManager` layouts the text for Kannada language. As other answers pointed out, `UITextView` is build around `TextKit` since `iOS7`, and thus uses `NSLayoutManager` internally to layout text.